# Why won't my button run my javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

Hi im having trouble figuring out why my button will not work below is my code any help is appreciated. basically once i hit button it should either print story with typed in words or if a spot is left blank story doesnt show and box thats missing characters is surrounded with red border
thanks.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title>assignment2</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id= "list">
<form id="form1" method="get">
<h3> Fill in the blanks and then press the submit button. </h3>
<label> Adjective
<input type="text" name="adjective"id ="adjective"/>
</label>
<br />
<br />
<label> Adjective
<input type="text" name="adjective2"id ="adjective2"/>
</label>
<br />
<br />
<label> Plural Noun
<input type="text" name="pluralnoun"id ="pluralnoun"/>
</label>
<br />
<br />
<label> Verb (ending in "ing")
<input type="text" name="verb"id ="verb"/>
</label>
<br />
<br />
<label> Edible object
<input type="text" name="edibleobject"id ="edibleobject"/>
</label>
<br />
<br />
<label> Monster
<input type="text" name="monster"id ="monster"/>
</label>
<br />
<br />
<label> Adjective
<input type="text" name="adjective3"id ="adjective3"/>
</label>
<br />
<br />
<label> Monster (again)
<input type="text" name="monster2"id ="monster2"/>
</label>
<br />
<br />
<label> Verb (ending in "ing")
<input type="text" name="verb2"id ="verb2"/>
</label>
<br />
<br />
<button type="submit" id="btn" name="btn"/>View Story</button>
</form>
</div>
<div id="story">
<p> Rain was still lashing the windows, which were now <span class ="adjective"> </span>, but inside all looked bright and cheerful. The firelight glowed over the countless <span class ="adjective2"></span><span class ="pluralnoun"></span> where people sat <span class ="verb"></span>, talking, doing homework or, in the case of Fred and George Weasley, trying to find out what would happen if you fed a <span class ="edibleobject"></span> to a <span class ="monster"></span>. Fred had "rescued" the <span class ="adjective3"></span>, fire-dwelling <span class ="monster2"></span> from a Care of Magical Creatures class and it was now <span class ="verb2"></span> gently on a table surrounded by a knot of curious people.
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#story p').hide();
    $('#form1').on('submit', function(event) 
    {
        for(var i=0 ;i<$('#form1 input').length; i++) //tyler suggested this to make it easier fo my error borders.
        {
            $('#form1 input').eq(i).removeclass("errorborder");
        }
        if (!formFilled()){
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            $('span.adjective').html($('#form1 input#adjective').val());
            $('span.adjective2').html($('#form1 input#adjective2').val());
            $('span.pluralnoun').html($('#form1 input#pluralnoun').val());
            $('span.verb').html($('#form1 input#verb').val());
            $('span.edibleobject').html($('#form1 input#edibleobject').val());
            $('span.monster').html($('#form1 input#monster').val());
            $('span.adjective3').html($('#form1 input#adjective3').val());
            $('span.monster2').html($('#form1 input#monster2').val());
            $('span.verb2').html($('#form1 input#verb2').val());
            $('#story p').show();
    event.preventDefault(); //Tyler informed me this would stop the page from refreshing and deleting the inputted words.
}

});
    function formFilled(){
        var filled=true;

        for(var i=0;i<$('#form1 input').length; i++)
        {
            if ($('#form1 input').eq(i).val() === "")
            {
                $('#form1 input').eq(i).addClass("errorborder");
                filled=false;

            } 
        }
        return filled;
    }
});
```

CSS code:

```
.errorborder{
    border:red, 3px,solid;

}
span {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: If you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for your code -- you'll have better luck getting assistance.

Comment: Where is your script.js code?
Also, you don't seem to have a button in your html code either...
EDIT: He added the rest

+1 to David, a jsFiddle would be better

Comment: Is this the actual layout of your code? Do you really have CSS and JS code outside the body tag? This may be confusing to people who tries to help you?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a poor substitute for a debugger.  Do you get any errors on the JavaScript console?  When you debug this, where specifically does it fail?  In what way does the code not behave as expected?  Is there a jQuery selector which doesn't find the element(s) you expect?  A logical path that isn't followed?  Please try to narrow down the problem.

Comment: because you have commas in your css...`border:red, 3px,solid;` should be `border:3px solid red;`...why werent you able to ask Tyler?

Comment: @David there is [code snipets](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) built into SO now

Comment: @Austin: And?  Stack Overflow may provide handy tools for debugging, but that doesn't mean the community at large is a replacement for a debugger.  Questions which essentially boil down to, "Here's all my code.  It doesn't work.  Figure it out for me." aren't a good fit here, regardless of any in-browser features offered by the site.

Comment: @david i meant that @ to be for David Tansey to let him know that there is functionality similar to jsFiddle built into SO now. I agree the community is not a debugger. Too many davids :)

Comment: @LoganMurphy fixed that little mistake thank you, i have asked tyler but he is also unsure why my button doesn't work.

Comment: @David my javascript console doesn't show any errors which is causing more confusion, this is my first time posting on this site so im not sure which way to show my code is better. I didn't mean for community to be a debugger everything in my code seems to work except for the button but i didnt know how to ask that question without posting my code here to show you guys what i mean, im in my first year of school for coding so most of this is new to me.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your JavaScript code, should be `.removeClass`, instead of `.removeclass`

Comment: @Givi thank you it now runs my story with proper words, just doesnt highlight errors still

Comment: @JustinWheeler: This sounds like a good opportunity to familiarize yourself with JavaScript debugging tools then.  For example, FireBug or Chrome tools.  This would allow you to set breakpoints in the code and examine its runtime behavior, line by line, examine the variables as they change, pause the execution of the code and test operations on the console given the current running state, etc.  These tools will be *invaluable* in your development efforts.

Comment: @Givi that would be a runtime error, not a syntax error

Comment: @LoganMurphy You're right, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used some of the suggestions in comments above, and changed around a few things myself and cleaned up the code. I've made it work...

The primary changes were

- change the form `method` to `post`
- change your `<button>` to `<input type="submit">`

please see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waqry5tL/) to see a working example of your code.

Hope you're able to see your mistakes by comparing with your own code!

Comment: feel free to "mark as best answer" if you liked my input ;)